# downloading files from my server to my local machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-s3, rsync

Hello I am running ec2 ubuntu instance, now I need to download few files to my local ubuntu machine from my server. How to do it.

I went through few instructions available on internet, which are not working for me.

Kindly help me in this regard.I am pretty much aware of ssh/scp and rsync

Comment: Is this a programming issue, or a linux-tools question?

Comment: @Mike Pennington:this is a linux-tools question

Comment: in the future, [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com/) is a better place to ask about apps on ubuntu.  Also, in order for someone to help, you should be specific about what you have tried (the exact CLI), as well as what did not work when you tried those things.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: thank you, I made a not of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeevan,

Copying from EC2 is the same as copying from any other machine. The only difference is, that if you want to pull the information from the EC2 instance, then you will need to use the key.

Example commands for copying FROM the EC2:

scp -i /path/to/key.pem user@ec2.com:/file.ext /localpath/

rsync -e "ssh -i /path/to/key.pem" user@ec2.com:/file.ext /localpath/

Good luck!

Dotan